# wordpress http to https redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to force my site to load in HTTPS. I can create a redirect in PHP which works for PHP files, but I want all requests forced to HTTPS - JS, CSS, Images, etc.

Here's what I have in my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have tried various methods of this by placing the redirect in different locations and such, but everything seems to make this into a redirect loop. Any ideas what I could do to fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your `http` to `https` rules before internal WP rule:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Make sure WP's `home URL` and `site URL` also have `https` in permalink settings.**

Comment: as always the htaccess guru :)

Comment: No need to add R=302. If no code is given a HTTP response, it defaults to 302 (temporally moved)

Comment: True but `R=302` is supposed to be placeholder while testing. It should be replaced with `R=301` after testing.

Answer (score 0):

Set a 301 permanent redirect which is more SEO friendly. Already tested:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all traffic to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Wordpress rules 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```